# Best practice to make a generator loop through a container infinite times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a generator to return elements from a container, but it needs to return/exhaust all elements then do it again.

The reason I say this is if there's a faster/better or more pythonic way to do this than just a for loop as I don't need them in order but I don't want to get the same item twice until it has exhausted all elements.

The example below is a tuple, although if there is a better container type for this than I'm all ears.

```
elements = ('a', 'b', 'c', ...)

def get_next_element():
    while True:
        for e in elements:
            yield e
```

There's got to be a different way to do this, or is this the best way?

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.cycle()` callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which does just that:

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

This does exactly what your pure-python function does, plus it caches elements so the input can be any iterator (not just a re-usable iterable such as a tuple), but does this in efficient C.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb.. Thanks!

Comment: One other really dumb question. Would a tuple be the best way to give these items to cycle? like could I just use `elements =  itertools.cycle('a', 'b', 'c', ...)` Or is that gonna cause an error as it only accepts one variable?

Comment: Right, just meant like instead of implicitly making a, b, c a tuple with the parentheses, is there any way to assume incoming variables are the iterable it's looking for. maybe use `*args`. I just don't like double open and close parentheses is all... I'm just being lazy and picky

Comment: @Jaba: if `cycle()` used `*args` then you could never pass in an endless iterable; that's legal and may have valid usecases where you combine arbitrary iterators wrapped in a `cycle()` object with `zip()` or `islice()` where you pull a limited number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer and added knowledge buddy